# How to run alert only once within range in if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, alert

```
function sendWeightAlert(){
 if(petInfo.weight >= 100 && previousWeight < 100){
  $(".treat-button").one("click", function(){
    alert(petInfo.name + " is going obese...");
  });
 }
}
```

Here basically what I want to do is to display the alert only once when the `petInfo.weight` is equal or over 100 and stop alerting every time after I click on the `treat-button`. I have tried to look for the answer and tried everything I could but it's not working... Please help me good code masters!!

Comment: you can use an additional variable to track if you haven't displayed the alert already when the condition is met

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable and check its state before showing the alert

```js
let showAlert = true;
$(".treat-button").click(function() {
  if ((petInfo.weight >= 100 && previousWeight < 100) && showAlert) {
    alert(petInfo.name + " is going obese...");
    showAlert = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring a global variable by default true,

make it false when you execute alert.

and add it in your if condition.

```
var isAlertShown = true;
```

and your function,

```
function sendWeightAlert(){
 if(petInfo.weight >= 100 && previousWeight < 100 && isAlertShown){
  $(".treat-button").one("click", function(){
    isALertShown = false;
    alert(petInfo.name + " is going obese...");
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var alerted = false;

var previousWeight = 99

var petInfo = {
  weight: 101,
  name: 'petName'
}

$(".treat-button").one("click", function(){
  if(!alerted && petInfo.weight >= 100 && previousWeight < 100){
    alerted = true;
    alert(petInfo.name + " is going obese...");
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="treat-button" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">TREAT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and it **actually wokrs fine** - so probably the reason is that you run sendWeightAlert() again **after** button click (which bind event handler again - and show alert after next click)

```js
let previousWeight= 10;
let petInfo = { weight: 100, name: 'dog' };

function sendWeightAlert(){
 if(petInfo.weight >= 100 && previousWeight < 100){
  $(".treat-button").one("click", function(){
    alert(petInfo.name + " is going obese...");
  });
 }
}


sendWeightAlert();  // here we bind handler only once, and jQuery `one` will run it once.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="treat-button">click me</button>
```